# What does the Quran tell us about helping others?

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer, helping

When something tragic ( earthquake, tsunami, floods)  occurs in the world Christians always reach out and try to help the victims, but Muslims don't unless the victims are Muslims themselves. What is the reason behind the latter.

Comment: All religions teach that you should love your neighbour, but Christianity is actually the only religion that says you should love your enemy.

Comment: Why would someone downvote lol

Comment: @aasheq, That is not true, in Surah Tawbah, Ayah 6 [quran.com/9/6](http://quran.com/9/6), it states that if your enemy seeks protection, you must grant him protection, show him Islam, and then escort him to place where he can be secure. The most _merciful_ generals would just let their enemies flee and hide away. Unless of course you have a different meaning of 'love'. Also, there are many other ayahs such as [quran.com/5/8] (quran.com/5/8) or [quran.com/42/39-42] http://quran.com/42/39-42) in which all have message of being just and fair to your enemy, and to forgive your enemy.

Comment: And to the OP, the latter of what you said (i.e. Muslims only help Muslims) is not true. For where I live, I know of many charities and causes that not only aim to benefit Muslims but to all people. A few examples are: http://www.islamic-relief.org.uk/, https://www.muslimaid.org/ and http://www.ifrc.org/

Comment: You must also take into account that Christian charities are more heavily funded than Islamic ones. As well as major poverty being inside of the Islamic countries themselves.

Comment: You have an incorrect premise in your question. Both the country of Pakistan and the Islamic Relief organization were quite involved with relief efforts in Nepal this time. Similarly in Haiti a few years ago. I will downvote until you can produce statistics that show that Muslims don't help others.

Comment: It might be the case that Muslims are helping too, but I have never read about SA, UAE and the other rich Arabic countries are s

Comment: As phrased, this seems to be more a question on why *people* choose to do (or not do) something, rather than a question on what *Islam* teaches.  Until you can expand the question to indicate that this behaviour is something that *is* (or can reasonably expected to be) promoted by Islam the religion, rather than just cultural norms (or personal opinions) held by Muslims, I don't see how it is on-topic here.

Comment: muslims don't tells their good deeds. they're not supposed to.

Comment: One brother asked me why we as muslims should help the khufars. When they don t repent, do they deserve our help?

Comment: you probably want to ask the question in [this manner](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1571/11938). Your question is good, but plz make sure you get some help so that it can be made comply to the rules. Maybe you can try getting some help in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Please, **this is a good question, *if asked properly***.